# Difference between these two SAS programs?

Tags: sas, variable-length

1. `data work.temp;
      length A B 4;
      infile '';
      input A B;
    run;`
2. `data work.temp;
      length A 4 B 4;
      infile '';
      input A B;
    run;`

Is there any difference between these two?

Answer (score 2):

No, check the properties of `work.temp` after running both. You should see that `A` and `B` are both set as numeric with length 4 in both cases.

Comment: so it's always better to use length A B 4 ?

Comment: It's a matter of preference. If you had vars a1 to a100, it would be possible to do `length a1-a100 4`, which is much better than `length a1 4 a2 4 a3 4...a99 4 a100 4`.